# What numerical error is Mathematica doing here and how can I avoid it?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

So I am solving a system of equations in Mathematica:

```
set1 = {1.60895*10^9, 56726.6}
set2 = {0.500000000000000/("C" "L"), (0.00333333333333333 (22500.0000000000 "C" + "L"))/("C" "L")}
Solve[set1==set2]
```

Mathematica gives me this set of solutions:

```
{{"C" -> 1.17523*10^-7 - 6.80827*10^-12 I, 
  "L" -> 0.00264426 + 1.53186*10^-7 I}, {"C" -> 
   1.17523*10^-7 + 6.80827*10^-12 I, 
  "L" -> 0.00264426 - 1.53186*10^-7 I}}
```

Which surprised me because I was not expecting a complex set of solutions. I have tried to do this by hand, using a calculator and, in fact, got real solutions. I assume there is some numerical error that is going on here and it is causing this. Any guess? How can I avoid it? Thank you!

EDIT:

Strangely the suggested answer works for the small workable example, but when I actually try to apply it in the code (the sets come from another protion of code) it does not work (but the sets should be the same...)

[image]

EDIT:

set1 correction of values to have exactly what is being propagated on the code

```
set1 = {1.6089544167593448*10^9, 56726.614765198035}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning message was very helpful.

```
Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
```

All you need to do is to [**`Rationalize`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html?v=13.2)

```
set1 = {1.60895*10^9, 56726.6} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
set2 = {0.500000000000000/("C" "L"), (0.00333333333333333 \
(22500.0000000000 "C" + "L"))/("C" "L")} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
res=Solve[set1 == set2]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Edit 1**

To make it numerical the following is sufficient

```
res // N
```

**Edit 2**

Explaining why the imaginary unit appears.

We can `Solve` the system with arbitrary symbolic coefficients

```
set1 = {x1 , x2}
set2 = {y1/(c l), (y2 (y3 c + l))/(c l)}
Solve[set1 == set2, {c, l}] // Expand
```

> [image: solve]

We can pass the values of the first and the second cases as rules and examine the square roots.

Let's do the first example

```
rules = {x1 -> 1608950000, x2 -> 283633/5, y1 -> 1/2, 
  y2 -> 3413029912987/1023908973896101, y3 -> 22500}
```

Then, all of the following

```
x2^2 y1^2 - 4 x1 y1 y2^2 y3 /. rules
y1 (x2^2 y1 - 4 x1 y2^2 y3) /. rules
x2^2 y1^2 - 4 x1 y1 y2^2 y3 /. rules
y1 (x2^2 y1 - 4 x1 y2^2 y3) /. rules
```

give positive numbers. For the second example, the rules are

```
rules = {x1 -> 3830920466304/2381, x2 -> 127473155643/2247149, 
   y1 -> 1/2, y2 -> 3413029912987/1023908973896101, y3 -> 22500};
```

and now the quantities under the square root are negative. Check the following

```
x2^2 y1^2 - 4 x1 y1 y2^2 y3 /. rules
y1 (x2^2 y1 - 4 x1 y2^2 y3) /. rules
x2^2 y1^2 - 4 x1 y1 y2^2 y3 /. rules
y1 (x2^2 y1 - 4 x1 y2^2 y3) /. rules
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! How can I put the result in numerical form again?

Comment: @GrangerObliviate - just use `N`, i.e., `Solve[set1 == set2] // N`

Comment: @GrangerObliviate please see the edit

Comment: or @BobHanlon's comment which I just saw

Comment: Can you please check my edit? For some reason in the "real" code, this does not work, this is really strange

Comment: @GrangerObliviate I don't understand what you mean. You get the solutions you wanted. If you do `\\N` which you have not done you will make them numerical

Comment: No, as you can see the top one still has a complex part...

Comment: @GrangerObliviate ok ok. I thought you meant brining it to numerical form does not work from the way you wrote it. Without the explicit expressions for the quantities that go into the `Solve` command, I cannot tell much. Note, however, that a `Chop` might take care of the imaginary part. But this is at the level of the numerics

Comment: I have just made a new edit correcting set1 to have the exact numerical values that are being propagated in the code.

Comment: @GrangerObliviate I added an edit that explains why the imaginary unit appears even in the symbolic computation

Comment: Ok, thank you, I guess then Mathematica is indeed correct, due to the high precision on the coefficients. Thank you.

Comment: @GrangerObliviate glad I was able to help :-)